# Why is it not necessary to catch the IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions, throws

I wonder why the `IllegalArgumentException` class does not *need* to be catched or declared, while other exceptions have to (eg `java.net.MalformedURLException`).

```
public void foo() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("spam");
}

public void bar() throws MalformedURLException { // required
    throw new MalformedURLException("ham");
}
```

I know that `Error`s do not have to be declared because they are not intended to be catched.

I'd like to declare a new exception which also does not require to be catched.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two types of Exceptions in Java: **Checked Exceptions** and **Unchecked Exceptions**. Checked exception has to be caught or declared to be thrown (like `MalfomedURLException`) but catching Unchecked exceptions (like `IllegalArgumentException`) is not mandatory and you can let the caller catch them (or throw them up to its own caller).

For more information, take a look at this post:

[Java: Checked vs Unchecked Exceptions Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)

If you extend your custom exception class from `RuntimeException` or any exception class inherited from it, then catching your exception will not be mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

`IllegalArgumentException` is unchecked exception , so if you do not catch it then it will be handled by JVM , these exceptions are sublclasses of `RuntimeException`, `Error`, while `MalformedURLException` is checked exception which must be caught by programmer.All `IOExceptions` are checked exceptions [Read here for more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)